# Is it possible to remove request query parameters from URL? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have a laravel query form using `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET']) !!}` with different query fields.

For example, I have fields like

- name
- category
- price

The user fills out the fields as required, however, even if a field is left ''blank'' (null) the query parameter appears in the URL
e.g sitename.com/products?name='test'&category=&price=

I was wondering if there's anyway to delete any empty parameters?

I've attempted adding an `array_filter()` to my return variable

`$query->paginate(24)->appends($request->query())` so that it would be

`$query->paginate(24)->appends(array_filter($request->query()))` however this does not affect the URL.

Some code for the request using the example is:

```
$query = Product::with('image')->visible(1); // visible is a custom attribute

if($request->get('name')) $query->where(function($query) use ($request) {
   $query->where('products.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('name') . '%')
   ->orWhere('products.slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('name') . '%');
     });

return view('browse.products', [
  'products' => $query->paginate(24)->appends($request->query())
]);
```

Comment: The browser is the one responsible for crafting the request once you submit the form. You can (1) have a submit handler which stops the default browser behaviour and uses e.g. `window.location.href = ...` to redirect how you'd like (2) create a server-side redirect that removes empty query parameters if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('get.index') . '?' . Request::server('QUERY_STRING'), 'method' => 'get')) }}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this method just now, and it still returns the string with empty params, when I @dd Request::server('QUERY_STRING'), it returns name='test'&category=&price=

Comment: try code after edit route name like answer